# Python multiprocessing pipe in fastapi server

Tags: python, pipe, fastapi, python-multiprocessing

I tried to write down a sample code that loads multiple keras models in subprocesses and performs inferences on API request.

Before expanding to multiple models, I tried loading only one model as a single subprocess and attempted to exchange data using multiprocessing pipe.

However, despite successfully exchanging data using pipes within the if **name** == "**main**" block, when I tried sending data through the pipe within the function that receives requests, the subprocess's pipe could not receive the data.

How can I achieve what I meant to do?

## Main Server

```
from multiprocessing import Pipe, Process

pipe_p, pipe_c = Pipe() # declare pipe in global

app = FastAPI()

@app.post("/api/test", response_model=MyResponse)
async def test(req:MyDataModel= Body(example=c.INFOEXAMPLE)):
    pipe_p.send(req)

    result = pipe_p.recv()

    return {
        "data": f"inference result: {result}"
    }

if __name__ == "__main__":
    p = Process(target=main, args=(pipe_c, model_type, model_name))
    p.start()
    # pipe_p.send("test") # successfully done
    uvicorn.run("main:app", port=port, host=host..)
```

## Worker main function

```
def main(pipe:PipeConnection, model_type:str, model_name:str):
    model = load_model(model_type)(model_name)

    while True:
        print("waiting...") #stuck here
        data = pipe.recv()
        print(f"received {data}")
        if data == "kill":
            pipe.close()
            return
        if data == "test":
            print(data)
            continue
        pipe.send(model(data))

    return
```

Comment: My advice: look into a task processing library like [Celery](https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/getting-started/introduction.html). They do exactly what you're after, offloading heavy calculations to separate processes (possibly on several machines), and you won't have all the headaches of manually sending data between processes.

Comment: AFAIK uvicorn starts multiple worker processes (so I guess you'll start multiple keras models) and uvicorn might pass incoming requests to any of them.